# cgi param() function did not work

Tags: perl, cgi, param

I met a problem with my perl script which is it just did not go through. As a beginner, I appreciate if anybody can explain it for me. As the Lincoln mentioned the param() is simple to use, but actually it is complicate. I read the cgi document and other examples, but could not figure out why this one is not working, which I copied from other's for test.
I believe my apache, perl and CGI.pm are installed correctly and running well with other examples but not this one.
Thanks a lot!

```
====================================================

  1  #!/usr/bin/perl -wT

  3  use strict;
  4  use CGI qw(:standard);

  6  my $q = CGI->new;

  8  my $filename = $q->param("name");
    #print $filename, "\n";
  10  my $contenttype = $q->uploadInfo($filename)->{'Content-Type'};

  12  print header;
  13  print start_html;
  14  print "Type is $contenttype<P>";
  15  print end_html;
```

====================================================
-------------Error message---------------------------------------------

```
error] [client 127.0.0.1] Use of uninitialized value in hash element at (eval 3) line 3.
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/Steve/Listing4-1-upload-file.cgi line 10.
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] malformed header from script. Bad header=tomato: Listing4-1-upload-file.cgi
```

Comment: @Sparky672 Lincoln Stein is the author of the CGI.pm module.

Comment: @tadmc,  that makes more sense now. Ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line of your script you enable the Taint mode of perl (`-T` switch). This is good.
But it will cause any content from outside of the script - including the params to your CGI script - to be tainted. Tainted content cannot be used in calls to certain system calls - see man perlsec. Before using this content you have to untaint the data.

This is probably what causes the problems here, since the variable `$filename` is tainted, saving the uploaded content won't take place and therefor `$q->uploadInfo( $filename )` will not return a hashref.
I would suggest at least two changes:

1. After obtaining the $filename untaint its content using a regular expression
2. After calling uploadInfo verify the success of the operation before you continue.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You will receive an error if you don't check that you actually have a file posted to your script. If you expect to use html to produce the form submission, that means you need a form element such as

```
<input type="file" name="name" />
```

Try this example instead. The extra `if` statements check for file to prevent referencing an invalid upload. We also present a simple for to test the upload case.

```
my $filename = $q->param("name");
my $contenttype = '';
$contenttype = $q->uploadInfo($filename)->{'Content-Type'} if $filename;

print header;
print start_html;
print '
<FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="/Listing4-1-upload-file.cgi" METHOD="POST">
Please select a file to upload: <BR/> 
<INPUT TYPE="FILE" NAME="name" />
<INPUT TYPE="submit">
</FORM>';
print "<p>file: $filename </p>" if $filename;
print "<p>Content-Type: $contenttype </p>" if $contenttype;
print end_html;
```

Comment: Thank JRideout! I just swallowed the code and give it a try to understand the param() function. Now I realise I have a long way to go.